# How to count the amount of items that were 'active' in a specific time?

Tags: r, date, count

### Background

I have the following data frame of projects:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 6/11/2019 | 4/7/2021 |
| 02 | 8/12/2021 | 1/18/2022 |
| 03 | 10/24/2019 | 12/3/2019 |
| 04 | 9/20/2021 | 11/11/2021 |
| 05 | 11/11/2021 | 11/11/2021 |

I also have a list of dates:

`date_list <- c(1/1/2020, 1/1/2021, 1/1,2022)`

I want to count how many projects were 'active' during those specific dates.

For example:
In 1/1/2020 there was only 1 project active which is project#1 because it started before and ended after 1/1/2020. in other words, it was an active project during that date.

### Current approach

```
for (date in date-list) {
  projects %>% filter(start_date <= date & end_date > date) %>% count()
}
```

This is taking too long as I'm working with a list of thousands of dates and a list of thousands of projects.

Answer (score 1):

You could first build a table of all open projects for a given date. Here's one way to do that

```
library(dplyr)
number_open <- rbind(
  data.frame(date=dd$end_date+1, open=-1),
  data.frame(date=dd$start_date, open=1)
) %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  summarize(open=sum(open), .by=date) %>% 
  mutate(open=cumsum(open))
```

That returns

```
        date open
1 2019-06-11    1
2 2019-10-24    2
3 2019-12-04    1
4 2021-04-08    0
5 2021-08-12    1
6 2021-09-20    2
7 2021-11-11    3
8 2021-11-12    1
9 2022-01-19    0
```

so for each date we can see when the number of projects changes.
We can this sorted lists of dates with `findInterval` to look up the number of open events for a given date

```
date_list <- as.Date(c("1/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "1/1/2022"), "%m/%d/%Y")
number_open$open[findInterval(date_list, number_open$date)]
# [1] 1 1 1
```

So there was 1 project open on each of these dates.
Tested with

```
dd <- read.table(text="
id  start_date  end_date
01  6/11/2019   4/7/2021
02  8/12/2021   1/18/2022
03  10/24/2019  12/3/2019
04  9/20/2021   11/11/2021
05  11/11/2021  11/11/2021", header=TRUE)
dd$start_date <- as.Date(dd$start_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
dd$end_date <- as.Date(dd$end_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to do this is to use [`data.table::foverlaps()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/foverlaps.html), a *fast binary-search based overlap join of two data.tables*.

First create two `data.table`s for the join. The `date_list` `data.table` will have a `dummy_date` field, as `foverlaps()` can find overlapping ranges. But in this case the start and end of the range will be the same.

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(projects)
# Create a data.table to join against
date_dt <- data.table(date = date_list, dummy_date = date_list)

# Set keys for join
setkey(projects, start_date, end_date)
setkey(date_dt, date, dummy_date)
```

Then we can do the join, group by `date` and count how many projects were open on each date:

```r
# Do the join
project_dates <- foverlaps(projects, date_dt, type = "any")

# Summarise by date
project_dates[!is.na(date), .N, date]
#          date     N
#        <IDat> <int>
# 1: 2020-01-01     1
# 2: 2021-01-01     1
# 3: 2022-01-01     1
```

##### Input data

```r
projects  <- structure(list(id = 1:5, start_date = structure(c(18058L, 18851L, 
18193L, 18890L, 18942L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), end_date = structure(c(18724L, 
19010L, 18233L, 18942L, 18942L), class = c("IDate", "Date"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

date_list <- structure(c(18262L, 18628L, 18993L), class = c("IDate", "Date"))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign `1` to the start date, `-1` to the end date, and `0` to the lookup date
2. Bind all the dates together into one table with their assigned values
3. Sort by date
4. Take the cumulative sum of the assigned numbers
5. Subset on lookup dates

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

date_list <- as.Date(c("1/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "1/1/2022"), "%m/%d/%Y")

setorder(
  rbindlist(
    list(
      projects[,.(date = c(start_date, end_date), inc = rep(c(1L, -1L), each = .N))],
      data.table(date = date_list, inc = 0L)
    )
  ), date
)[,n := cumsum(inc)][inc == 0L][,inc := NULL][]
#>          date n
#> 1: 2020-01-01 1
#> 2: 2021-01-01 1
#> 3: 2022-01-01 1
```

Data:

```
projects <- structure(list(id = 1:5, start_date = structure(c(18058, 18851, 
18193, 18890, 18942), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(18724, 
19010, 18233, 18942, 18942), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about the expected result, but this adds a count of how many *date_list* entries are active per *project* row.

Note: convert the dates to Date objects with `projects$start_date <- as.Date(projects$start_date, "%m/%d/%Y")` and `projects$end_date <- as.Date(projects$end_date, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Preparation

```
library(data.table)

setDT(projects)

date_list <- c("1/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "1/1/2022")
```

```
projects$active <- rowSums(sapply(as.Date(date_list, "%m/%d/%Y"), \(x) 
  data.table::between(x, projects$start_date, projects$end_date)))
```

result

```
projects
   id start_date   end_date active
1:  1 2019-06-11 2021-04-07      2
2:  2 2021-08-12 2022-01-18      1
3:  3 2019-10-24 2019-12-03      0
4:  4 2021-09-20 2021-11-11      0
5:  5 2021-11-11 2021-11-11      0
```

##### Data

```
projects <- structure(list(id = 1:5, start_date = structure(c(18058, 18851, 
18193, 18890, 18942), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(18724, 
19010, 18233, 18942, 18942), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `tidyr::crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

crossing(date_list, projects) %>%
  filter(between(date_list, start_date, end_date)) %>%
  count(date_list)

#----
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date_list      n
  <date>     <int>
1 2020-01-01     1
2 2021-01-01     1
3 2022-01-01     1
```

Example data

```
projects <- structure(list(id = 1:5, start_date = structure(c(18058, 18851, 
                                                              18193, 18890, 18942), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(18724, 
                                                                                                                            19010, 18233, 18942, 18942), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
date_list <- as.Date(c("1/1/2020", "1/1/2021", "1/1/2022"), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

---

Since all combinations are created, this is likely not the most efficient solution. But a quick test on ~1,800 dates runs in a second or two

```
dates_tst <- seq(as.Date("2018-1-1"), as.Date("2023-1-1"), by = '1 day')


projects_tst <- data.frame(projects = 1:length(dates_tst),
                           start_date = dates_tst - 100,
                           end_date = dates_tst + 100)


crossing(dates_tst, projects_tst) %>% # 3.3M combinations
  filter(between(dates_tst, start_date, end_date)) %>%
  count(dates_tst)

#----
# A tibble: 1,827 x 2
   dates_tst      n
   <date>     <int>
 1 2018-01-01   101
 2 2018-01-02   102
 3 2018-01-03   103
 4 2018-01-04   104
 5 2018-01-05   105
 6 2018-01-06   106
 7 2018-01-07   107
 8 2018-01-08   108
 9 2018-01-09   109
10 2018-01-10   110
# i 1,817 more rows
```